# Yosemite fail - how do I revert back to snow leopard?

Tags: macos

How can I revert back to snow leopard? My machine won't start up. Macbook pro 17"

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). More detail needed - what Macbook model precisely, what went wrong; why you think you need to revert to an older OS...

Answer (score 2):

- Power off the Mac and then power it on holding option
- Insert the Snow Leopard DVD once the grey screen is presented and choose to boot from Snow Leopard media
- Wipe the Mac with Disk Utility (erase/repartition the internal drive)
- Install Snow Leopard

Your Mac should have come with CD/DVD discs that allow you to reinstall the OS. Boot the system from that media (insert disc hold C while booting) and reinstall the OS. You can order a replacement from Apple or get one on the used market if you don't have yours.

Comment: Nice, nice answer. Since the question is simply "how to X" - I've removed the extra backup part. The OP can ask how to back up in a separate question since that's far too broad to answer all the OP needs in one post.